# How to change language mode of VSCode programmatically?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have tried `vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode', 'JSON');`. But it does nothing more than open a panel. And `TextDocument.languageId` is an readonly property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1800) is the corresponding issue on GitHub. You should upvote (thumbs up) it to tell them we want this.

Comment: Looks like that feature is implemented now.

Answer (score 5):

It was implemented at some point (**1.28.0**+ probably):

```javascript
vscode.languages.setTextDocumentLanguage(activeEditor.document, languageId);
```